# Add slide down effect when user taps on more button in reverse list view in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I created a list view in which I am showing 8 lines text to user with More button. And when user taps on More button, it will expand to full text. This is a message listing, so list start in reverse order means from the bottom of the screen.

Because of reverse order in list view, when user tap on More, it always slide up widget. But I want to slide down the widget in reverse list view. Please check expected and current result in attached video

I used [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_text) to expand and collapse text widget in list view

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUphh.gif)
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy0WW.gif)

Answer (score 0):

To the scroll view or list view add a page storage key

```
ListView(
 key : PageStorageKey('chat'),
...
)
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it is not working.